# How to show additive subgroup of $R^n$ is not discrete?

Tags: lattice-crypto

Suppose we have the additive subgroup of reals generated by $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5}$. How would you show you that this subgroup does not form a lattice?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as asked it's a math question with no motivation

Comment: "How would you show you that this subgroup does not form a lattice?"; are you sure it's not?  Isn't the group $\{a\sqrt{3} + b\sqrt{5}\}$ trivially isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$?  Isn't the latter a lattice?

Comment: @poncho Okay but it should be discrete (this is the definition). More precisely it should contain a shortest vector. I think, without a proof, one can find arbitrarily small vectors in this group.

Comment: "More precisely it should contain a shortest vector"; the meaning of 'shortest' depends on the metric; for the traditional metric on $\mathbb{R}$ ($dist(A, B) = |A-B|$), it's straightforward to show there are arbitrary short vectors.  For another metric, say, $dist( A\sqrt{3}+B\sqrt{5}, C\sqrt{3}+D\sqrt{5}) = |A-C| + |B-D|$, there is a shortest nonzero vector

Comment: There’s a frustrating divergence between the mathematics and cryptography communities around the meaning of “lattice”. Cryptographers talk about lattices using the Euclidean metric, rather than the more general mathematical definition.

Comment: I have not migrated this question to math-SE because they have [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73262) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/852210).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that there exists a sequence of arbitrarily short vectors, i.e. integer sequences $a_n, b_n$, such that

$$|a_n\sqrt{3}+b_n\sqrt{5}| \to 0$$

For this explicit example, note that an obvious choice of $a_n$, $b_n$ is

$$a_n\sqrt{3} = -b_n\sqrt{5}\iff -\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \sqrt{5/3}.$$

One can't exactly choose $a_n, b_n$ to satisfy this inequality ($\sqrt{5/3}$ is irrational).
Instead, we choose sequences $a_n/b_n$ of increasingly good rational approximations of $-\sqrt{5/3}$.
One can do this explicitly via [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).
For example, [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=continued+fraction+of+sqrt%5C%2840%29Divide%5B5%2C3%5C%2841%29%5D&key=vctge) states the relevant continued fraction is $[1, 3, 2, 3, 2,\dots]$, meaning $1 + \frac{1}{3 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\dots}}}$.

Anyway, the various finite truncations of this continued fraction will be a sequence of increasingly good rational approximations to $\sqrt{5/3}$.
As the continued fraction is infinite, we can keep repeating this process, leading to $a_n, b_n$ such that $|a_n\sqrt{3}+b_n\sqrt{5}|\to 0$.

If $-\sqrt{5/3}$ were rational, its continued fraction would be finite, and the above argument would eventually fail.
Note that this means that something like the subgroup generated by $\sqrt{3}$ and $5\sqrt{3}$ *is* a lattice --- it is the lattice $\sqrt{3}\mathbb{Z}$.
It is important that we didn't consider the subgroup generated by $\sqrt{3}, 5\sqrt{3}$ and 1 here --- this is no longer a lattice, by (roughly) the same argument.